# CI Platform that support Android builds and Fastlane

Tags: android, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am looking to begin using a CI platform for my Android builds. However, I would like it to officially support fastlane as I would like to be able to push builds to the play store depending on the commit tags.

I was looking at Circle CI but the android-sdk is only "officially" supported on Ubuntu 12/14 and not on OSX and it doesn't seem like fastlane is supported on those systems.

Is there one that supports both?

Answer (score 0):

Actually is supported, you can run your usual fastlane lanes inside the CircleCi machine. Just do you usual bootstrap and install the fastlane dependency

**circle.yml**

```
dependencies:
    pre:
      # Install fastlane
      - yes | gem install fastlane
```

And finally

```
test:
    override:
      - fastlane <YOUR_FASTLANE_LANE>
```

Btw I'm using ubunto and it works.